# Url rewrite on both www and non-www

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a couple of rules in IIS to redirect incoming requests to pages with file extensions, so for example mysite.com/hello/ is directed to www.mysite.com/hello.aspx

I have a rule which caters for the trailing slash so I don't end up with www.mysite.com/hello/.aspx

this is fine but it's not working for requests that start with www
so, www.mysite.com/hello is staying the same

I tried putting an additional rule for anything matching the pattern www* but doesn't seem to work.

Any advice much appreciated

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="(.*)/$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="AddASPX" enabled="true">
                <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: 2 Questions: what's `<add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />` there for? Why not using `Redirect` for your first rule's action?